# Multiple Vue instances bind to parent & child elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, instance

I would like to ask for best setup of **Vue instances** (components), when I do not want use SPA.

My **HTML** looks like:

```html
<html>
  <div id="layout">
    <div>Some Layout based content...</div>
    <div id="homepage">
      <simple-form-component></simple-form-component>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type=text/javascript src="homepage.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src="layout.js"></script>
</html>
```

Currently I have simple example ot two **.js** files:

- layout.js
- homepage.js

```
// layout.js

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
new Vue({
    el: '#layout',
});
```

```
// homepage.js

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import SimpleForm from '../../../../components/SimpleForm.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#homepage',
    components: {
        SimpleForm,
    },
});
```

It seems to work fine, but I am suspicious that this is not 100% correct, due to console error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

Do you have any ideas/experience how to setup my scenario correctly?

PS: I would like to have my JS split into different files, managed by webpack and distributed by backend.

Thank you,
Mario

Comment: You could mount Vue only on `homepage` and remove that div if you do not want your page to behave like an SPA.

Comment: Actually yes, in this simplified example, but imagine I would like to add some components (like bootstrap-vue components) to **layout** also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found workaround `v-pre`, my HTML will change the line: `<div id="homepage" v-pre>`. One small issue is, that I will not see my components in **Vue Devtools**.